# Real Analysis Methodologies to Prove $-\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt=\gamma+\log(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}\,dt$ for $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

> **MOTIVATION:**

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907978/cosine-integral), the OP asked to prove the [Cosine Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) identity

$$-\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt=\gamma+\log(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}\,dt$$

where $\gamma $ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  However, the two posted answers are incomplete and seem unsatisfactory.

---

> **Proof Using Complex Anaysis**

One can show for $x>0$ that $-\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt=\gamma+\log(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}\,dt$ using contour integration.  To wit, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_\epsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx +\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{iRe^{i\phi}}}{Re^{i\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_R^\epsilon \frac{e^{-x}}{ix}\,i\,dx+\int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_\epsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx -\int_\epsilon^R \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx-i\frac\pi2+O(\epsilon)+O\left(\frac1R\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

whence after taking the real part of both sides of $(1$ and integrating by parts the integral $\int_\epsilon^R \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$ with $u=e^{-x}$ and $v=\log(x)$, we find

$$\begin{align}-\int_x^R \frac{\cos(x')}{x'}\,dx'&=\log(x)-\int_\epsilon^R e^{-x}\log(x)\,dx+\int_\epsilon^x\frac{\cos(x')-1}{x'}\,dx'\\\\
&-\log(\epsilon) -e^{-R}\log(R)+e^{-\epsilon}\log(\epsilon)+O\left(\frac1R\right)+O(\epsilon)\tag2
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to 0$ in $(2)$ yields the sought relationship.

---

> **Proof Using Real Analysis**

Alternatively, we can use either the [Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) or ["Feynman's Trick"](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf) to show that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac1{x+1}\right)=0\tag3$$

Starting with $(3)$, is tantamount to starting with the real part of $(1)$ and we are done.

---

> **QUESTION:  So, what are other ways to prove the coveted relationship using real analysis tools only?**

Answer (score 0):

Note that for each $x>0$, the improper integral $\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$
converges conditionally (in the sense that $\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\int_{x}^{A}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$
exists but $\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\int_{x}^{A}\left|\frac{\cos(t)}{t}\right|dt=\infty$).
Define $F:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $F(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$.
Note that we still have $F'(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$. For, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
F'(x) & = & \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{x+h}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt-\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt}{h}\\
 & = & -\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+h}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt}{h}\\
 & = & -\frac{\cos(x)}{x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

On the other hand, $0$ in the integral $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}dt$
is a removable singularity. For $t\neq0$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t} & = & \frac{(1-\frac{1}{2!}t^{2}+\frac{1}{4!}t^{4}-\cdots)-1}{t}\\
 & = & -\frac{1}{2!}t+\frac{1}{4!}t^{3}-\frac{1}{6!}t^{5}+\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
Define $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(t)=-\frac{1}{2!}t+\frac{1}{4!}t^{3}-\frac{1}{6!}t^{5}+\cdots$.
It can be proved that the power series converges everywhere (using
root-test), and hence $\phi$ is an analytic function. Therefore $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}dt=\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt$.

Now $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}dt=\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}$.

Finally, define $G:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
G(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt-\left[\ln(x)+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}dt\right].
$$
Then $G$ is differentiable and $G'(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0$.
This shows that $G$ is a constant function.

Comment: You have not evaluated the constant, which renders this development incomplete.  But I appreciate your attempt.

Comment: I thought that you just asked to prove that there exists a constant $\gamma$ such that ... You did not ask explicitly "compute the value of $\gamma$".

Comment: Read the question of the OP.  "Real Analysis Methodologies to Prove $-\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt=\gamma+\log(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}\,dt$ for $x>0$."   The constant $\gamma$ is explicitly written.  How did you infer that I was interested in something considerably less than that.  Furthermore, in the body of the question, I actually show two derivations that include $\gamma$.

Comment: I interpret that line as "Prove that there exists $\gamma$ such that ... for all $x>0$.

Comment: You should state explicitly: Compute the value $\gamma$ and express it in close-form. Otherwise, I can write $\gamma = G(1) = \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}t dt - \int_0^1 \frac{\cos t -1}{t} dt$.

Comment: This question is an explicit statement and even includes a reference to another MSE question.  The symbol $\gamma$ is a common and standard designation of the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant).  So, augment your question or delete it please.  I have just added to the opening statement in th body of the question to avoid any further future ambiguity.

Comment: Unlike $\pi$ or $e$, "Euler-Mascheroni constant" and the symbol $\gamma$ is not very common. You should state it in your question at the very beginning. Now your question is OK.

Comment: I suggest that you take time to actually read the comments!  I just provided you a reference that refutes your assertion that $\gamma$ is not a common designation for the EM constant.   Therein it states "The Euler–Mascheroni constant (also called Euler's constant) is a mathematical constant recurring in analysis and number theory, usually denoted by the lowercase Greek letter gamma ($\gamma$)." So stop with your unfounded and easily refuted statements/assertions.

Comment: Inasmuch as your answer is not useful, it has been down voted.

Comment: Without mentioning the name "Euler–Mascheroni", no one know the meaning of the symbol $\gamma$. What you did is just writing the symbol $\gamma$ directly at the beginning and at later time adding a line "where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant".

Comment: The symbol $\gamma$ is used in more than one way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma

Comment: First Dany, I've given you a reference that refutes your claim.  Second, the second and third words of the opening sentence in the BODY of the question embeds a reference (which you evidently did not bother to read) in which the EM constant is EXPLICITLY mentioned.  Third, in the BODY of the question, there is a derivation of the coveted relationship in which a very well-known integral representation of the EM constant is explicit.  To appease YOU, I edited the opening statement.  Fourth, the meaning of $\gamma$ should be implicitly clear from the CONTEXT of the question.